# How to practically customize IE context menu?

Tags: c++, internet-explorer, activex, browser

I need to add one menu item in IE context menu. It is similar with Google customized context menu "Search Google for xxx" when you right click on IE.

I did a research and found that overriding IDocHostUIHandler::ShowContextMenu in a IE BHO can customized IE context menu. The sample project can be found in Popup blocker project published in codeproject. It works well and is easy to implement. **However this approach has a problem. The problem is it will conflict with other add-ons' context menu customization per MSDN.**

In MSDN Internet Explorer Center forum, there are some discussions about this topic. However there is not a proper implementation posted.

If anybody has experience on this, please share your idea. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

See *[Adding Entries to the Standard Context Menu](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa753589(VS.85).aspx)* on MSDN.

For some sample code, download and extract the [Web Accessories for Internet Explorer 5](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/ie/ie6/previous/webaccess/ie5wa.mspx) (the mechanism still works in IE versions up to and including 8).  Look at `ie5wa.inf` and `*.html` for examples of various IE context menu extensions.

Note that the abive is achieved without COM, purely via one registry setting and a file containing a blob of script (Javascript, JScript, VBScript etc.)  The script (JScript, VBScript) may in turn work with COM objects, should your menu action logic reside in such an object, e.g.

- create a `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\MenuExt\My &Context Menu" registry key (`&` precedes the [menu accelerator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keyboard_shortcut) letter, if any)
- set the default value for the key to point to a file containing the script code implementing the context menu action(s), possibly interacting with a COM object (must support `IDispatch` IIRC; also read up on the [My Computer Security Zone](http://surfthenetsafely.com/ieseczone3.htm))
- create a binary `contexts` value (`0x02` for images, `0x10` for selections, etc.) which regulates when the new context menu should be displayed

Answer (score 0):

I customized my IE in order to navigate to a selected text. You can read the full story and get detailed source code [here](http://www.h3mm3.com/2011/06/select-right-click-and-navigate-from-ie.html).

The hearth of my solution is built around the following javascript code and the Registry key [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\MenuExt]:

```
  var parentwin = external.menuArguments;
  var doc = parentwin.document;
  var sel = doc.selection;
  var rng = sel.createRange();
  var str = new String(rng.text);

  if(0 < str.length)
  {
    if (str.indexOf("http")!=0)
        window.open("http://"+str, "_blank");
    else 
        window.open(str, "_blank");
  }
```

Comment: Of course, you'll end up with customizing my javascript code in order to navigate to "http://www.google.com/search?q=<str>" instead of navigating to <str>"